# Matching of specific strings

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a file and a list. I want to search the elements of list in file.

File:

```
        ayush_6standrard_jeevansaral
      ayush mahnotra_jigar (4, 9
           rahul
               meera_gajjar (2, 4


        smita_8standrard_coral
      smita patel_yash (5, 7
           gunjan
               vidya_dalal (1, 6
```

List:

```
lst = [ayush,smita,gunjan,rahul]
```

I want to extract the data in another file as:

```
ayush,mahnotra_jigar
rahul,meera_gajjar
smita,patel_yash
gunjan,vidya_dalal
```

I have tried the code but not getting what conditions to be kept for name in one line and related name in another line:

Code:

```
with open(file.txt, 'r') as i_file, open(output.txt, 'w') as o_file:
     temp_lst = ['{0} '.format(ele) for ele in lst]
     line = i_file.readline()
     l = line.strip()
     while line:
            if l.startswith(tuple(temp_lst)) == True:
                o_file.write(l[:l.index(' ')] + ',' + l[l.index(' ')+1:l.index('(')]
            elif condition(?):
                name = l
                line = i_file.radline()
                l = line.strip()
                o_file.write(name + ',' + l[:l.index('(')])
            line = i_file.readline()
            l = line.strip()
```

This is just a sample example. The file is too big and different. Can someone help me to find this condition. So, it would search for a line where only the element of list is present?

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions.

In the below code, pattern is the regular expression to find the matching pair of names. `findall` will find all the matches. Iterate over the matches and write into the output file.

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+\(")
with open("in.txt") as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    matches = pattern.findall(data)
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
        for a,b in matches:
            fout.write(f"{a},{b}\n")
```

Comment: Can you provide a solution other than regular expression? As, I am not familiar with regular expression